# How to store files that can be downloaded from Android App?

Tags: android

I'm new to Android App development. I have some audio files that has to be downloaded to the App when the user requests it. Where do i store these files and how do i access them through the network.
Example - Im developing a music player App. I need to store songs somewhere in the net and develop the capability in the App to download them. Where do i store them?

Comment: Why would you want to do something like that?

Comment: store on a webserver

Comment: after downloading or for downloading itself where to store and how to access them is your doubt??

Comment: Example - Im developing a music player App. I need to store songs somewhere in the net and develop the capability in the App to download them.
Where do i store them?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can build a project at google app engine. You can take advantage of the cloud platform.
[google app engine](https://appengine.google.com/)